# Loop categories, get category image

Tags: magento-1, search, catalogsearch

I have added categories to search, so it displays categories matching to search term(s) and below them products.

I can not get category image. I know these categories have images because they are shown in subcategories when navigating in categories.

How I can loop these categories found through and get image to it ?
This search works and displays correctly category name but `$_imgHtml` is currently empty

```
    echo "<div class=\"search-term-notice\" style=\"float:left; clear: both;\">";
    echo "Categories found:";

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($this->helper('catalog/category')->canShow($category) && stripos($category->getName(), $searchTerm) !== false)
        {
            $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
            if ($_imgUrl = $category->getImageUrl()) {
                $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
                $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        }
            echo $_imgHtml;
            echo "<h3><a href='".$category->getUrl()."'>".$category->getName()."</a></h3></p>";
        }
    }
    echo "</div>";
```

print_r from $category:

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category Object ( [_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_category [_eventObject:protected] => category [_cacheTag:protected] => catalog_category [_useFlatResource:protected] => [_designAttributes:Mage_Catalog_Model_Category:private] => Array ( [0] => custom_design [1] => custom_design_from [2] => custom_design_to [3] => page_layout [4] => custom_layout_update [5] => custom_apply_to_products ) [_treeModel:protected] => [_urlModel:protected] => [_defaultValues:protected] => Array ( ) [_storeValuesFlags:protected] => Array ( ) [_lockedAttributes:protected] => Array ( ) [_isDeleteable:protected] => 1 [_isReadonly:protected] => [_resourceName:protected] => catalog/category [_resource:protected] => [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/category_collection [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1 [_isObjectNew:protected] => [_data:protected] => Array ( [entity_id] => 169 [entity_type_id] => 3 [attribute_set_id] => 3 [parent_id] => 99 [created_at] => 2016-01-18 17:20:04 [updated_at] => 2016-04-18 17:20:04 [path] => 1/2/99/169 [position] => 1 [level] => 3 [children_count] => 0 [is_active] => 1 [include_in_menu] => 1 [request_path] => test1/testdeep.html [name] => Test deep 1 [url_key] => test_deep [path_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 99 [3] => 169 ) ) [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1 [_origData:protected] => Array ( [entity_id] => 169 [entity_type_id] => 3 [attribute_set_id] => 3 [parent_id] => 99 [created_at] => 2016-01-12 17:20:04 [updated_at] => 2016-04-18 17:20:04 [path] => 1/2/99/169 [position] => 1 [level] => 3 [children_count] => 0 [is_active] => 1 [include_in_menu] => 1 [request_path] => test1/testdeep.html [name] => Test deep 1 [url_key] => test_deep ) [_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id [_isDeleted:protected] => [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: can you show `print_r($category)` ? Also try `$category->getThumbnail();`

Answer (score 0):

Just like the product, the category is an EAV (entity attribute value). Therefor when you load a collection of EAVs you need to specify which attributes to be loaded in that collection.

You need to edit the file where you load the category collection and add the attributes to select:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: so how exactly that works inside that foreach ?

Comment: You need to do that before you loop the collection. You need to locate where the collection is loaded, where the $categories variable is set. That's where you need to do this